# Closed operators

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, operator-theory, supremum-and-infimum, closed-graph

I was wondering whether the following statement is true or not?

*If $A$ is closed, then it follows from the closed-graph theorem
that it is bounded iff $D(A)$ is closed.*

I found this in a chapter of a book on operator theory; a counterexample can be the operator $A=d/dx: D(A)(\subset C[a,b])\to C[a,b]$ which is closed when the domain $D(A)$ is chosen to be $C^1[a,b]$. Under the sup-norm, space $D(A)=C^1[a,b]$ is closed, however, the operator is not bounded.

Comment: No, $C^1([a,b])$ is not closed under the sup norm. (For example: Any continuous function is a uniform limit of polynomials...)

Comment: You have just proved that $C^1[a,b]$ is not closed in $C[a,b]$. :)

Comment: You are right, :))